# Cannot change NULL to 0 (MySQL Query)

Tags: mysql, null

### MySQL Server version: 5.7.25-28-log - Source distribution

I get 131 rows when I run this in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE newsletter = 0
```

I get 685 rows when I run this in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE newsletter is null
```

But when I simulate this query in phpMyAdmin, I get 0 (zero) rows

```
UPDATE bookings SET newsletter = 0 WHERE newsletter is null
```

Any idea why the simulation is failing?

Grateful for anything anyone has to offer

### UPDATE

Here is a screenshot after running the query simulation

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Add output of `show create table bookings` please

Comment: The `UPDATE` command does not "get" any rows, so it is nonsensical to expect to get anything other than "0 (zero) rows".  You probably mean to say something else.  Well, precision in explaining your problem is of paramount importance.  Showing the exact output of the tools you are using instead of trying to describe it might also yield better results.

Comment: @MikeNakis I don't use PhpMyAdmin, but other similar tools report the number of rows that were updated, and I assume that's what he meant.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I can assume the same just as easily. But the point is that the OP must use more precise language and not rely on readers assuming stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "simulation"? PhpMyAdmin doesn't simulate anything, it performs actual database queries.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the simulation, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i guess your "simulate query" runs in a transaction with rollback..

just for simulate the query / check syntax...

like a dry run

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=548a364a40ac226ef847cc62630f373a

if you click "go" probably it will run your query without auto rollback

Comment: Yes, the simulator is like a dry run so that we can see how many rows would be affected before actually running it live, it is a safety net but I do not understand why the query matches zero rows, when it should match 685 rows

Comment: @user12534088,

if you try with other values it return different than 0 rows?

I am not familiarized with phpAdmin..

but if you use any other odbc client and do a rollback it show 0 rows updated..

if you click 'go' it update the rows, dont?

Comment: I'm concerned about clicking Go before knowing what will happen, this is why I want to simulate it first

Comment: it will works, be sure.. the 0 rows affected is expected cause de transaction rollback.. that is the only way that
the phpAdmin can do a dry-run...

but if you are afraid, you cant run it in a staging environment?

Comment: I see, ok, I will create a duplicate of the database and test it, thank you

Comment: good luck! 
and consider to alter the column to not null default(0)

if null value is not desired in the column